# Angular execute passed method reference in correct context

Tags: angular

I've created a component `si-button`, which works as a progress button (when clicked, a loading indicator is shown).

I pass a reference to the method to be executed on click to the `si-button` component like this:

```
<si-button [pb-click]="register">Register</si-button>
```

The `register` method returns a promise, and the loading indicator is shown as long as the promise isn't resolved.
In the `SIButtonComponent` class, the `register` method is executed when the button is clicked.

`SIButtonComponent`:

```
export class SIButtonComponent{
    ...

    @Input('pb-click') pbClick : () => Promise<any> = null;

    handleClick($event){
        this.loading = true;

        this.pbClick().then(() => {
            this.showSuccess();
        }, (data) => {
            this.showError();
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

`RegisterComponent`:

```
export class RegisterComponent{
    register() : Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.auth.register(this.email, this.password).subscribe((org : Organization) => {
                resolve();
            }, (error : ErrorResponse) => {
                reject();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Problem**
Since the method `register` is executed from an instance of `SIButtonComponent`, `this` refers to the `SIButtonComponent` instance rather than `RegisterComponent`. How should I do this correctly? It would make more sense to use `@Output` rather than `@Input` for the `pb-click` parameter, but I don't know how I could get the `Promise`-instance after emitting the click event then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an arrow function instead:

```
export class RegisterComponent {
    registerFunction = () => this.register();
    ...
}

<si-button [pb-click]="registerFunction">Register</si-button>
```

Comment: This works great, but why? I want to understand the mechanics behind :)

Thank you!

Comment: Because an arrow function is bound to `this`. That's the main reason (other than the reduced verbosity) why they exist. It's equivalent to `function() { return this.register(); }.bind(this)`.